# Integrating slide animation to calendar months

Tags: jquery, css

I've built a two-column/month calendar from scratch using flexbox and I'm trying to integrate the ability to slide one month at a time left and right by clicking the left and right arrows.

I tried integrating my calendar with a carousel slider plugin, but there was too much conflicting CSS and I couldn't control which month displayed first, other than placing it first within the HTML.

Now, I'm trying to manually build the sliding functionality with jQuery and CSS, but I've never done something like this before, so I'm unsure how to approach it. All of the necessary months will be immediately available, and hidden as necessary, within the HTML. The class `.calendar-half-inactive` would be applied to months not in view, but I can probably handle this once I get the months sliding.

This is my mark-up (with one month):

```
<section id="event-calendar" class="fullwidth">
  <div id="calendar-cont">
    <div class="calendar-half">
      <div class="calendar-half-cont">
        <h1>January 2017</h1>
        <div class="table">
          <div class="table-cont-arrow">
            <div class="table-cont-dates">
              <div class="table-row table-header">
                <div class="table-cell">S</div>
                <div class="table-cell">M</div>
                <div class="table-cell">T</div>
                <div class="table-cell">W</div>
                <div class="table-cell">T</div>
                <div class="table-cell">F</div>
                <div class="table-cell">S</div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell"></div>
                <div class="table-cell"></div>
                <div class="table-cell">1</div>
                <div class="table-cell">2</div>
                <div class="table-cell">3</div>
                <div class="table-cell event-on">4
                  <div class="tooltip tooltip-right cal-tooltip">
                    <div class="cal-tooltip-cont">
                      <div class="cal-tooltip-img four-three-img">
                        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr06/14/7/enhanced-5869-1400067973-7.jpg" alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-info">
                        <a href="#"><h2>Wrapping content title in tooltip</h2></a>
                        <h3>Event date</h3>
                        <h3>Event venue</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cal-tooltip-cont">
                      <div class="cal-tooltip-img four-three-img">
                        <img src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr06/14/7/enhanced-5869-1400067973-7.jpg" alt="" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-info">
                        <a href="#"><h2>Wrapping content title in tooltip</h2></a>
                        <h3>Event date</h3>
                        <h3>Event venue</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cal-see-all">
                      <a class="link-gray" href="#">See All <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-cell">5</div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell">6</div>
                <div class="table-cell">7</div>
                <div class="table-cell">8</div>
                <div class="table-cell">9</div>
                <div class="table-cell">10</div>
                <div class="table-cell">11</div>
                <div class="table-cell">12</div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell">13</div>
                <div class="table-cell">14</div>
                <div class="table-cell">15</div>
                <div class="table-cell">16</div>
                <div class="table-cell">17</div>
                <div class="table-cell">18</div>
                <div class="table-cell">19</div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell">20</div>
                <div class="table-cell">21</div>
                <div class="table-cell">22</div>
                <div class="table-cell">23</div>
                <div class="table-cell">24</div>
                <div class="table-cell">25</div>
                <div class="table-cell">26</div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-row">
                <div class="table-cell">27</div>
                <div class="table-cell">28</div>
                <div class="table-cell">29</div>
                <div class="table-cell">30</div>
                <div class="table-cell"></div>
                <div class="table-cell"></div>
                <div class="table-cell"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar-arrow">
              <a class="icon-arrow-right link-gray" href="#"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Attempted jQuery:

```
var monthWidth = $('.calendar-half').outerWidth();

$('.calendar-arrow .icon-arrow-left').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.calendar-half').animate({
    left: '+=monthWidth'
  });
});

$('.calendar-arrow .icon-arrow-right').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.calendar-half').animate({
    right: '+=monthWidth'
  });
});
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/qrRVxJ) (with two months)

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: use fullcalendar.io jQuery plugin https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @YaseenAhmed I would, but I get the impression that restyling this plugin would take as long as manually building the sliding animation. I have a very specific design that I can't change